# Extend a generic class in java with a particular type

Tags: java, generics

I'm new in java and I just discovered generics. I thought i understood the principle till i tested this code.
I wanted to create a class SortedListOfStrings, extending ArrayList that would insert an element in lexical order in the list.

```
public class SortedListOfStrings<String> extends ArrayList<String> {
    
    public boolean add(String s) {
        boolean done = false;
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<this.size(); i++) {
            if(get(i).compareTo(s) > 0) {
                this.add(i,s);
                done = true;
            }
        }
        if(!done) {
            this.add(i, s);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

But I caught this error : **The method compareTo(String) is undefined for the type String   SortedListOfStrings.java line 11**

Can someone explain me why I do have it or what I did wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic classes allow you to create a class that will work for any type specified within the `<>` angle brackets (Java allows you to restrict which types can be specified, but that is a discussion for another time). This means that in the class definition, the type you specify within the angle brackets is an arbitrary type parameter.

In this case, you are saying that the arbitrary type parameter is named `String`. This `String` is just a stand-in for another type. Because you specified `String` as the name of your type parameter, `String` in the context of this class is just a stand-in that could be any type. Usually, generic type parameters are named with a single capital letter (like `T`) to avoid conflicting with existing types. Your `String` type is overriding (in the non-programming meaning of the word) the `java.lang.String` type you are used to. Because `String` in your class is generic, there are no guarantees that the type for which it is a stand-in has a `compareTo` method, hence the error.

The `extends` keyword basically means that your class inherits all the methods of another class. You may need to override (this time I mean "override" in the programming meaning) some methods from that other class, meaning you provide your own implementation, in order to get it to work.

I don't believe that what you are trying to do with this class is a good fit for a generic type parameter because, judging by its name, you don't want it to be generic. You are wanting it to work only with strings.

You might want to do something like this instead:

```
public class SortedListOfStrings {
    private ArrayList<String> list = ArrayList<>();
    
    public void add(String s) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < list.size() && s.compareTo(list.get(i)) < 0)
            ++i;

        list.add(i, s);

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much. It's clear now.
Before your answer, I did test something like this that works : public class SortedListOfStrings extends ArrayList<String>. Is it clean to process like this ?

Comment: Generics can be confusing when you first learn about them. Keep programming and eventually their use and purpose will become crystal clear to you.

Comment: I would recommend just having private field with a `list` like in my example if you are wanting to keep the functionality simple. If you want to implement all the regular features of a list, however, you might consider implementing the `java.util.List` interface. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html